# Accessing synonym of DB link object

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, synonym, dblink

Background:
We have database FIN having schema as FIN_DEV.

We have another database APP having schema APP_DEV.

A DB link is created in APP_DEV pointing to FIN_DEV

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK FINDEV_FIN
CONNECT TO FIN_DEV
IDENTIFIED BY <PWD>
USING 'FIN'
```

We are able to access the objects in FIN_DEV from APP_DEV using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TBL_FINA FOR TBL_FINA@FINDEV_FIN
```

All good until this point.

Here comes the question:

Another schema INT_DEV in APP database needs to access SYNONYM TBL_FINA from INT_DEV.

Could you please let me know the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how; I don't have your users (and don't feel like creating them), so:

- my remote database = `orcl` (it is your `fin` database)
- user in my remote database = `my_remote_user` (it is `fin_dev` in your database)
- user in my local database = `scott` (`app_dev` in your database)

  - it'll create a database link and a synonym
- another user in my local database = `mike` (`int_dev` in your database)

---

In a **remote database**, I'm creating a table to mimic your situation:

```
SQL> create table tbl_fina (id number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into tbl_fina values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL>
```

Connecting to **local database**, creating a database link & a synonym:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> create database link findev_fin
  2  connect to my_remote_user
  3  identified by its_password
  4  using 'orcl';

Database link created.

SQL> -- Testing, whether the DB link works
SQL> select * From dual@findev_fin;

D
-
X

SQL> -- Creating a snynonym
SQL> create synonym tbl_fina for tbl_fina@findev_fin;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from tbl_fina;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

So far, so good - this is what you currently have.

---

Now, let's allow another user - in my local database - to access that synonym. Straightforward solution is to grant select on it, right?

```
SQL> grant select on tbl_fina to mike;
grant select on tbl_fina to mike
                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02021: DDL operations are not allowed on a remote database


SQL>
```

Whooops! That won't work. A workaround is to create a **view** (on the synonym) and grant select on that view to `mike`:

```
SQL> create view v_tbl_fina as select * from tbl_fina;

View created.

SQL> grant select on v_tbl_fina to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

That works. Finally, connect as another user and select from the view (i.e. a synonym):

```
SQL> connect mike/pwd
Connected.
SQL> select * from scott.v_tbl_fina;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

For easier access - to avoid naming view owner (`scott`) - `mike` can now create its own synonym:

```
SQL> create synonym tbl_fina for scott.v_tbl_fina;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from tbl_fina;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL>
```

---

Certainly, another option is to create a database link in my `mike` user, but that's kind of dangerous as database link allows its owner to do virtually *anything* in the remote database, as it is now identified by the remote username and its password.

Comment: Thanks, @Littlefoot.  Really appreciate the way you explained step by step.  I tried and it works.  Thanks again!!